# Create date from string in ISO format

Tags: javascript, date, format

My function is receiving a date in string format as '2019-09-20T04:30:01Z'. I want to convert it to beginning of the day. Expected output is '2019-09-20T00:00:00Z'.

The Date() object gives me a date along with timezone on which if I do setHours(0) the resultant object is '2019-09-19....'

Answer (score 2):

You could just take the date and add the zeroed time part.

```js
var string = '2019-09-20T04:30:01Z',
    result = string.slice(0, 10) + 'T00:00:00Z';

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `.match()` instead of `Date()` object

```js
const date = '2019-09-20T04:30:01Z';
let res = (date.match(/^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T/) || [null])[0]
res && (res += '00:00:00Z')
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to modify the string:

```js
let s = '2019-09-20T04:30:01Z';

console.log(s.split('T')[0] + 'T00:00:00Z');
console.log(s.replace(/T.*/,'T00:00:00Z'));
console.log(s.substr(0,11) + '00:00:00Z');
console.log(s.substring(0,11) + '00:00:00Z');
console.log(s.slice(0,11) + '00:00:00Z');
```

If you want to use a Date (which doesn't seem necessary), then zero the UTC hours and use *toISOString*, but you'll need to remove the milliseconds if you don't want them:

```js
let s = '2019-09-20T04:30:01Z';
let d = new Date(s);

d.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(d.toISOString().replace('.000',''));
```